# Numerical Methods for Higher Order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking for some numerical methods to solve higher-order ODEs. That is, the ones that contain 4th and 5th derivatives. What can one use? Should I be looking at RK and/or its modifications? Euler’s method? Finite differences?

In case it matters, the equation I am needing to solve is a linear, fifth order equation with single-point boundary conditions.

**Edit:**

In essence, it is a special case of the Cauchy problem:

$a\frac{d^5y}{dx^5} + b \frac{d^4y}{dx^4} + c \frac{d^3y}{dx^3} + d \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + e \frac{dy}{dx} + f y = 0$,

where $a,b,c,d,e,f $ are known constants
and the initial value condition is as follows

$y(0)=0, \frac{dy}{dx}(0)=3, \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}(0)=-9, \frac{d^3y}{dx^3}(0)=-8, \frac{d^4y}{dx^4}(0)=0$

Comment: Providing the equation would be helpful, because the choice of methods doesn't just depend on the order

Comment: I believe a standard approach is to rewrite the ODE as a system of first-order ODEs, then apply a numerical method for solving first-order systems of ODEs.

Comment: The answer to your question really depends on a lot more than just knowing the order of the derivatives that appear in the equation. Other important decision criteria would be the type of initial or boundary conditions that are provided and if the equation is explicit or implicit in the highest ordem derivative.

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks! I have added the equation as an edit to the question.

Comment: I agree with littleO, you can turn this into a linear system of 1st order ODE, and I even believe there's an exact solution you can get with some linear algebra. Or alternatively use any suitable finite difference scheme, like RK